# Exercise $11$, Section $3.B$ - Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Exercise: Suppose $S_1,\dots,S_n$ are injective linear maps such that $S_1S_2\cdots S_n$
makes sense. Prove that $S_1S_2\cdots S_n$ is injective.

Proof: We prove by induction. clearly $S_1$ is injective. Suppose inductively that $S_1S_2\cdots S_{n-1}$ is injective. We want to show that $S_1S_2\cdots S_n$ is injective. We are given that $S_n$ is injective and that $S_n(v)\in Domain(S_{n-1})$. By the induction hypothesis we know that $S_1S_2\cdots S_{n-1}$ is injective. Hence, $S_1S_2\dots S_n$ is injective.

Is the proof correct?

Edit: I thought of a different proof.

Proof $2$: Given that $S_1,\dots,S_n$ are all injective. We see that for any $u,v\in \text{domain }S_n$ we have that $S_n(u)=S_n(v)\implies u=v$.

Then we have that $S_{n-1}(S_nu)=S_{n-1}(S_nv)\implies S_n(u)=S_n(v)\implies u=v$.

Continuing on in this fashion we conclude that $S_1\cdots S_n$ is injective.

Comment: You are at this level, that $n\in \Bbb{N}$ shouldn’t bother you. Just prove the result for $S_1, S_2$. This problem is elementary set theory problem, you don’t need linear condition.

Comment: @user264745 Yeah I agree. I actually found another proof using linear algebra. Using the theorem that a linear map is injective if and only if null$T=\{0\}$. Then we can use this theorem to show that the composition is injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one small subtlety, which is that at no point do you prove that the composition of exactly two injectives is injective. You can fix this in one of two ways. First, you can deduce this from your inductive hypothesis, by choosing $S'_1 = S_1...S_{n-1}$, $S'_2 = S_n$ and then choosing $n-2$ maps to be the identity, which are also injective, in order to apply the hypothesis.

The second thing you could do, is just use strong induction instead of induction. This is the same as induction, except instead of assuming that $S_1...S_{n-1}$ is injective, you assume all compositions of injectives of length less than $n$ remain injective. Now the hypothesis includes the case of $2$ maps.

A third thing you could do is make your base case for induction the case of $2$ linear maps. Then the proof of the inductive step would follow from the base case. This might be the most elegant approach.

That strong induction is equivalent to induction has been discussed elsewhere on this site.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am maybe misunderstanding strong induction, but I think I used strong induction in my proof. I assumed that the composition $S_1S_2\cdots S_{n-1}$ is injective.

Comment: Strong induction would have a hypothesis of the form, "for all $m < k$, assume that the composition of $m$ injective linear maps is again injective." What you did was assume that exactly $n-1$ maps that are injective have an injective composition. This is why I suggested you could fix it by tacking on a bunch of identity maps, which are obviously injective. But I think strong induction is more elegant than this.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: The argument seems rather straight forward. Please correct me if I am wrong.

It is obviously true for $n=1$

Suppose that it is true for $n=k$.

Then for $n=k+1$, $S_1S_2...S_k\left (S_{k+1}(x_1)\right)=S_1S_2...S_k\left(S_{k+1}(x_2)\right) $implies that $ S_{k+1}(x_1)=S_{k+1}(x_2) $ since $S_1S_2...S_k$ is injective by induction assumption. Finally $S_{k+1}(x_1)=S_{k+1}(x_2)  \implies x_1=x_2$ because $S_{k+1}$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

Another method:

A matrix $M$ induces an injective linear map if and only if there is a matrix $B$ so that $BM = I$ (to see this, use the row reduction algorithm). So if each $M_i$ is injective we have a $B_i$ satisfying $B_iM_i = I$, and so $\prod M_i$ is injective by virtue of the fact that $\left(\prod B_{n-i}\right)\left( \prod M_i \right)= I$.

Comment: Yeah that also works. Nice proof!

Comment: To pull back the (admittedly thin) curtain, this proof is just a specialization of the fact that if $f_i$ has a left inverse $g_i$, then $f_1 \circ \dots \circ f_n$ has left inverse $g_n \circ \dots \circ g_1$, hence is injective.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_1S_2...S_{n-1}S_n(u)=S_1S_2...S_{n-1}S_n(v)$ where $u,v\in domain(S_1S_2...S_n)$

or $S_1S_2...S_{n-1}(S_n(u))=S_1S_2...S_{n-1}(S_n(v))$

$\implies S_n(u)=S_n(v)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \            (\because S_1S_2....S_{n-1}$ *is injective by hypothesis*)

$\implies u=v\ \ \ \ \   (\because S_n$ *is injective*)

so, $S_1S_2...S_{n-1}S_n$ is injective.